# How do I get GPUImage animating with a still image source?

Tags: ios, image-processing, gpuimage

I have tried to setup a simple GPUImage environment in a UIViewControler.  However, I get a blank screen.  I want to animate a property of the swirl filter whilst the source image is kept constant.  How can I do this?

I want good performance (> 30 fps) for large-ish images so would ideally like to avoid unnecessary pixel copies back and forth from GPU to CPU.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];

    self.stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
    self.swirlFilter = [[GPUImageSwirlFilter alloc] init];
    self.swirlFilter.radius = 0.8;

    self.filteredImageView =
    [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,
                   self.view.frame.size.width,
                   self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:self.filteredImageView];

    // GPUImagePicture -> GPUImageFilter -> GPUImageView
    [self.stillImageSource addTarget:self.swirlFilter];
    [self.swirlFilter addTarget:self.filteredImageView];

    NSAssert(inputImage && _stillImageSource && _swirlFilter && _filteredImageView,
             @"Something unexpected is nil");
}

// Set up a the display link in View Did appear     

- (void) displayLinkDidFire:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink
{
    CGFloat proportion =
    [RSHelper proportionForTime:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];

    self.swirlFilter.angle = proportion;

    // Do I need to call some kind of update call here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer - I was just missing a call to `processImage` on the `GPUImagePicture`

```
- (void) displayLinkDidFire:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink
{
    self.swirlFilter.angle = [Helper calcProportion];
    [self.stillImageSource processImage];
}
```

`GPUImage` is actually quite nice to setup and it seams to be faster than `CoreImage` as it stated in the [GPUImage docs](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#overview).  It pains me to use a 3rd party lib over some apple's technology, but I don't see any advantage or CoreImage.

Comment: I may need to redo those benchmarks at some point, because Core Image got quite a bit faster in iOS 6 and I wasn't performing as much of an apples-to-apples test as I thought (the sepia filter is odd in Core Image for interesting reasons). Core Image does have the advantage of being able to run on the CPU when an application goes into the background, which I cannot do.

Comment: @BradLarson You have made me unsure now :) - I was trying out both CoreImage and GPUImage - it seamed like CoreImage was dropping more frames.  I might have missed some performance enhancements tho.  What is the advantage of running on the CPU?  Something to do with thread safety?

Comment: You can't do any operations on the GPU when your application is in the background. If you try, your application will be killed instantly.